# How to open links in a page in new tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is this code the best solution to get all links in a page in an array:

```
 var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Or is there a better solution than this?

After this, how can I open all links in the array "allLinks[i]" in new tabs?

Comment: the tabs should open the links in the array

Comment: Use the `for` loop to iterate through the array.

Comment: Does this help?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript][1]
You can loop through the array and do that.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: Wow, that was a very quick answer to comment conversion, must have been automated.

Answer (score 2):

Just attach a new 'target' attribute to all the 'a' html tags and Chrome will open all the links in a new tab by default.

With jQuery the answer is easy.

```
$('a').each(function(){ $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); });
```

Or in pure javascript

```
var allLinks, link, _i, _len;

allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (_i = 0, _len = allLinks.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  link = allLinks[_i];
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Or in coffee script

```
allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for link in allLinks
 link.setAttribute 'target', '_blank'
```

Comment: The *target* attribute specifies where to open the link.

Comment: var allLinks = document.links;
  var link;

  for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
   allLinks[i].style.backgroundColor='#ffff00';
 link = allLinks[_i];
   link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
}

Comment: link = allLinks[i]; **not**  link = allLinks[_i]; **or** var allLinks = document.links; var link; for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) { allLinks[i].style.backgroundColor='#ffff00'; allLinks[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); }

Comment: and i think there is an extra }. look at the debug console in chrome and google the errors.